# eigen values and vectors in this question

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix to be solved for landa. here is the matrix with my answer (sorry for the wrong equation writing format):

[image]

but the correct equation from this matrix should be (when simplified):

[image]

Please explain what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Note: Your 2x2 entry should be $-\lambda$.

Comment: I still can't drive the above equation. Where does the 2 come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplace development with respect to the first row:
\begin{align}
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -\lambda & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
&=
(1-\lambda)\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda & -1 \\
0 & 1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
-
\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=-\lambda(1-\lambda)^2-(1-\lambda-1)\\
&=-\lambda(1-\lambda)^2+\lambda\\
&=\lambda(1-1+2\lambda-\lambda^2)\\
&=\lambda^2(2-\lambda)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Your centre matrix component should be $-\lambda $ not $\lambda $

Then you would get:

$-\lambda (1-\lambda)^2-(1-\lambda-1)=-\lambda (\lambda^2-2\lambda)=0$

Thus $\lambda^2(2-\lambda)=0$

Comment: I still cant get the correct result! where does 2 come from?

Comment: I've put in an edit, hope all is clear now

Answer (score 1):

There is a sign error with $a_{22}$ as it should be negative.

We have:

$$(1-\lambda)(-\lambda(1-\lambda))-(1(1-\lambda)-1) = -\lambda^3 + 2 \lambda^2 = \lambda^2(2-\lambda) = 0$$